# evolution and mutation of microrganisms against medicines?

Tags: evolution, adaptation

I presume microorganisms would have very short life span and they would multiply more creating millions of their kind. Is it really a threat to consider when we use anibiotics and other stuff more making these creatures becoming resilient to the medicines. On the other hand bodies becoming dependent on the medicine making us weaker .we clean our office spaces homes etc with bleaching agents, acids killing microorganisms and thus making our body unaware of these and letting these organisms survive and create more deadly strains.

I believe there are examples like malaria microbes becoming resistant to `quinine` perhaps many more.  If someone tries not to take medicines when he suffers from common cold and small fevers and let the body fight but is it right to do so considering that mecines are available and one should take them.

There is an [article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2616794/Antibiotic-resistance-needs-taken-seriously-AIDS-Implications-bacteria-evading-drugs-devastating-says-landmark-report.html) also published today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few throughts about this: Microorganisms have a short life span but they replicate very fast with a short generation time. So this create vast amounts of "offsprings" with some mutations naturally occurring. Due to this large numbers the chance of developing resistances is much higher than for slowly replicating species.

This is especially true, when the selection pressure is high, as this is the case when you treat with drugs which usually kill these microbes efficiently. When people are not taking these drugs (antibiotics for example) according to the necessary scheme, the concentration of the drug in the body is lower than necessary to kill of all microorganisms. This leads to the survival of microorganisms which are a bit adapted to survive the drug and so on.

The real problem are people who are not following their treatment regime necessary and thus causing resistancies. A case for this is tuberculosis. Regarding taking medication: Always take them when necessary and leave them out when not. A simple cold for example can not be treated antibiotics since it is viral, the secondary middle ear infection usually can.

Comment: Great answer.  I'll add that there is debate in medical circles (especially primary care) whether to treat mild ear infections (without hearing alterations) with antibiotics at all, since statistical analyses are showing that the vast majority resolve on their own naturally without treatment (source: UpToDate, PubMed) and the more antibiotics are used, the more resistance develops.

Comment: Also, there used to be widespread overuse of antibiotics for upper respiratory infections when most URI are viral, sinus infections are usually secondary to viral and far more rare than people think, and (similar to ear infections) frequently resolve on their own (sources same). Overuse of antibiotics has caused resistance, as discussed.  We're causing bacterial evolution right in front of our eyes.  Look up MRSA, VRE, and multi-drug resistant organisms (MDRO).  It's scary to wonder how close we could be to an epidemic of bacteria resistant to everything we currently have!